Hanoi towers with moving K rings on each step. Proof number of steps
So we have the popular Hanoi puzzle
with N rings, 3 rods.
As we know it’s proved that the steps
for moving all rings from the first to the third are $ \ge 2^n - 1$.
Now I have the puzzle with moving K rings on each step (like having K hands which we can use at the same time)
So if we have N hands, the puzzle can be solved in 1 step.
I need a formal proof that it can be done in $\ge 2^{\frac{n}{k}} - 1$
My attempt: We can group the N rings into subgroups (each with K rings, only the last with $<k$). And the task is solved as the normal tasks. The count of the groups are $ \frac{n}{k} $.
Any help with the formalization?

You haven’t fully defined the problem. You have $k$ hands and there are 3 spindles: a source, a destination, and a staging spindle? And what happens to the disks in the $k$ hands? Or maybe there are $k$ staging spindles?

I don't understand the rules.  Do you mean that you move $K$ rings as a single block?  I don't think that helps you... Or are you just saying that we take $K$ moves in the ordinary sense and call them a single move?  I suggest:  edit your post to include an explict example with a smallish number of rings.  Say $6$ rings with $K=2$.   You claim you can do this in (at most) $7$ moves, right?  Should be easy to write out.  Better yet, try $(N,K)=(6,3)$.  Now you claim you can do it in at most $3$ moves.

As a general comment:  I suggest avoiding words like "group" and "subgroup" in this context.  At first I thought you were talking about some algebraic structure but you aren't, right?  You just meant "subsets".

Correction:  In my comment I shouldn't have written "at most".

I beleive that your attempt is correct. From there to have a formal proof you also need to show that the move done "as the normal tasks" are valid moves for your groups of k rings and your modified rules.

Let's remember the proof that $2^n-1$ steps are required for the usual towers of Hanoi puzzle. Then, we will modify that proof to get a proof that works for this variant.
Let $T(n)$ be the minimum number of steps required for $n$ rings in the usual towers of Hanoi puzzle. At some point in the puzzle, the largest ring needs to be moved onto the destination rod, which means that the remaining $n-1$ other rings need to be stacked on a different rod. It takes at least $T(n-1)$ steps to move these $n-1$ smaller rings off of the largest ring, because this subtask is isomorphic to version of the puzzle with $n-1$ rings. So, it takes $T(n-1)$ moves to free up the largest ring, then one move to put the largest ring in its place, and finally $T(n-1)$ more moves to move the stack of $n-1$ rings back on top of the largest ring. Putting this altogether implies
$$
T(n)\ge 2T(n-1)+1.\qquad (n\ge 2)
$$
Using this recurrence relation, we can prove that $T(n)\ge 2^n-1$ by induction on $n$. The base case where $n=1$ is obvious. Assuming that $T(n-1)\ge 2^{n-1}-1$, we get
$$
T(n)\ge 2T(n-1)+1\ge 2(2^{n-1}-1)+1=2^n-1.\tag1
$$
Now, how does this change for the version where you can move $k$ rings at a time? Let $S_k(n)$ be the number of moves required for this variant. This time, we can instead prove
$$
S_k(n)\ge 2S_k(n-k)+1\qquad (n\ge k+1)
$$
The proof idea is the same, but the only difference is that during the critical step where we move the largest ring to its destination, we can move $k-1$ other rings along with it, so that only $n-k$ need to moved off of the largest ring before this can happen.
With this modified recurrence relation, we can prove that $S_k(n)\ge 2^{\lceil n/k\rceil}-1$ by induction on $n$. Again, it is trivial to show this inequality when $n\le k$. Now, assume by strong induction that the inequality is for all numbers less than $n$. To prove it for $n$, we use a calculation which is similar to $(1)$.
$$
S_k(n)\ge 2S_k(n-k)+1\ge 2(2^{\lceil (n-k)/k\rceil}-1)+1=2\cdot 2^{\lceil n/k\rceil-1}-1= 2^{\lceil n/k\rceil}-1.
$$
